# Ошибка You have an error in your SQL syntax. при добавлении параметра с переменной

Tags: c#

Ошибка синтаксиса при добавлении параметра с  textBox1.Text

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN ? TEXT", sqlConnection);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", textBox1.Text);

        try
        {
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дайте ссылку на документацию, статью или любой другой ресурс, где вы почерпнули способ задания параметра с помощью `?`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все проще чем кажется.

```
string escapedStringColumnName = MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlHelper.EscapeString(textBox1.Text);


if (!new Regex("[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9]+").IsMatch(escapedStringColumnName))
    throw new Exception();
MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN `" + escapedStringColumnName + "` TEXT", sqlConnection);

                try
                {
                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы не можете иметь имя столбца как параметр.

Вы либо добавляете его в строку сами, что может быть небезопасно.

Либо выполняете вот такой запрос:

```
SET @a = ?;
SET @stmt = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE docs ADD COLUMN ', @a, ' TEXT');
PREPARE myquery FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE myquery;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE myquery;
```

Comment: @ - запомните в MySql нет такого, есть ?

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста как исправить мою проблему на языке C#. Просто нужен код

Comment: @СерегаWend - _в MySql нет такого, есть ?_ - в любой РСУБД параметры либо есть, либо их нет. А способ их записи в коде - `?`, `@name`, `:name` и т. п. - зависит от _провайдера_. [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_Parameters.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Сдается мне, что у вас изначально неверный подход к работе с БД. Вы не должны добавлять в таблицу `Students` столбцы всякий раз, когда хотите добавить новый предмет. У вас классический случай отношения **многие-ко-многим**.

**Студент**--m--**Имеет**--n--**Предметов**

Вам надо создать еще две таблицы: `Предметы` и `СтудентыПредметы`. И тогда, в случае добавления нового предмета, вы просто добавляете его в тб. `Предметы`. А если вам нужно для **студента Вася** добавить **предмет Палатка**, то вы записываете новую строку с `Id` **студента Васи** и `Id` **предмета Палатка** в таблицу `СтудентыПредметы`.

Comment: Точно подмечено!

Comment: Вы вообще бред написали, я хочу добавлять столбцы в БД это мое личное дело просто напишите мне пример как это сделать. Не нужно мне писать того что вообще мне не нужно

Comment: @СерегаWend - вам написали, как сделать правильно. В любой нормальной конторе уволят за проектирование БД, как в вашем коде.